# How to Redirect LWR Digital Experience Users to SSO URL Using URL Redirects?

Tags: experience-cloud, redirect, digital-experience, lwr

- We have a LWR experience site that was created before winter'23, so `/s` prefix exists for most of our pages and our home page url is something like this: `acme.customer.com/s/`
- We use **Google** as the auth. provider, so we don't need below out of box urls that platform creates. We tried deleting this but it is not possible(Don't remember the exact error).

  - `acme.customer.com/s/ForgotPassword`
  - `acme.customer.com/s/CheckPasswordResetEmail`
  - `acme.customer.com/s/SelfRegister`
  - `acme.customer.com/s/login`
- If a user enters any of the above urls, we want to redirect user to below url:

  - `acme.customer.com/services/auth/sso/google_sso_login`

### Options available:

#### [Salesforce Sites URL Redirects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_redirects.htm&type=5)

- Below is what I tried but it is not working. Any url redirect rule that I add here that starts with prefix `/s` is ignored.

[image]

#### [Redirect Users to Your Experience Builder Site Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_url_redirects.htm&type=5)

- I prepared csv file as per the documentation and uploaded but it is a relative url redirect. It is not able to remove `/s` prefix.

[image]

#### [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation)

- This is the only option that is working for now. We have a dummy component on all of these pages that redirects user to sso url using NavigationMixin. User experience isn't that great and there is a flickering effect.

Is there a better solution for my use case?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it. We can use go up directory syntax(`..`) in Target URL field.

1. Prepare a csv file using below:

   ```
   /acme/s/login,/../services/auth/sso/Google_SSO_Login,301
   ```
2. Upload the csv file as per this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_url_redirects.htm&type=5

With this setup all urls originating from `<base-domain>/acme/s/login` will be redireced to `<base-domain>/acme/services/auth/sso/Google_SSO_Login`